# passing sys.argv in pytest tests

Tags: python, pytest, command-line-arguments, argv

I have this code in `script.py`:

```
...
async def main():
    max_requests = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 1
    txt_file = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else "urls.txt"
    ...

asyncio.run(main())
```

So I can run this script in CLI (with optional arguments) and in another modules. It has two arguments, and I trying to write unit tests with pytest for that script in `test_script.py`, but get an error:

```
    max_requests = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 1
E   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test_script.py::TestScript::test_01'
```

I have read that pytest use its own arguments and I have tried to remove this arguments passing empty or slicing list to `sys.argv` in test:

```
    def test(self):
        sys.argv = []
        # or sys.argv = sys.argv[1:]
```

But it didn't help. Нow to get around pytest arguments and run tests with correct arguments from script?

Comment: make a list of arguments to be tested. `argv = 'myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3'.split()`

Comment: It's unclear. Post a [mre] and debugging details. Anyway, it seems the ```asyncio.run(main())``` was executed inside the ```test_script.py```, and it will if you didn't call that inside the ```if __name__ == '__main__':```.

Comment: @relent95 Thanks! Yes, you are right, adding `if __name__ == '__main__':` solves this error.

Comment: Why not edit the question and answer your own question for future readers?